# H2 db: How to solve Function "TOP" not found; SQL statement

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

Hi I wrote query using spring Specification and it looks like this.

```
select
        distinct TOP(?) project0_.idproject as idprojec1_40_,
        project0_.status as status2_40_ 
    from
        project project0_ 
    inner join
        project_info projectinf1_ 
            on project0_.idproject=projectinf1_.idproject 
    where
        lower(projectinf1_.proj_name) like ?
```

It works fine using real database but when I use h2 local database I got this error in console:

```
2017-10-16 18:58:56.808  WARN 14500 --- [io-8090-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90022, SQLState: 90022
2017-10-16 18:58:56.808 ERROR 14500 --- [io-8090-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Function "TOP" not found; SQL statement:
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:

  datasource:    
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:file:~/project-data/dev;MODE=MSSQLServer
    username: sa
    password:
    initialize: True

  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:        
        ddl-auto: create 
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect

        hbm2ddl:
          auto: create  
          import_files: enums.sql, import.sql
```

Any suggestions how to solve it?
**EDIT:**
Usage

```
Page<Project> page = projectRepository.findAll(getSpecifications(params), 
getPaging(params));

static Pageable getPaging(SearchParams params) {
    Integer pageNumber = params.getPageNumber() != null ? params.getPageNumber() : 0;
    Integer pageSize = params.getPageSize() != null ? params.getPageSize() : 15;
    return new PageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize);
}

static Specifications<Project> getSpecifications(SearchParams params) {
    return Specifications.where(new SearchSpecifications(params));
}

public class SearchSpecifications implements Specification<Project> {
    // some methods
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Project> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    // conditions
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#select

Comment: "it works fine using real database" - h2 is a real database!

Comment: thank you for your answers I edited my post with exmaple how I am using it. Could you provide me an example how to get it work with h2?

Comment: there is still `TOP(?)` instead of `TOP ?`?

Comment: yes it is copied sql log

Answer (score 0):

H2 doesn't support select like this (where you use distinct and top together): `select distinct top X attribute` whereas other engines do. I think this is the reason.